# how to get http response from typescript post

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

I have tried looking at other questions but they dont seem to help. I have the following method in typescript

```
transferAmount(transfer: Transfer): Observable<number> {
return this.http
  .post<number>(
    `${this._baseUrl}:8092/api/transfers/`,
    transfer,
    { observe: "response" }
  )
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((response: any) => {
      console.log(response.json());
      const location = `${response.headers.get("Location")}`;
      console.log(parseInt(location.slice(location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)))
      return of(parseInt(location.slice(location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)));
    })
  );
```

}

I have tried to log the response using

```
console.log(response.json())
```

but this does not work?

Comment: Please provide some more information: What doesn't work? Of what type is `this.http`? What does the API resource return – JSON, XML, nothing?

Best would be if you provide a minimal reroduction in a StackBlitz project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this:

```
this.transferAmount(transfer: Transfer).subscribe(resp => JSON.stringfy(resp));
```

When you do a request the post method return an observable to you, but you need to subscribe in that observable to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer when you subscribe to your observable like this :

```
transferAmount(..).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```